# How to get the DisplayName of the selected ModernTab in ModernUI?

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I create dynamically ModernTab in the code behind with their informations (DisplayName and URI source).

Initialization of the ModernTab:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
    <mui:ModernTab Layout="List" Name="listEcole"
                   PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="ModTab_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind :

```
List<string> listEcoles = MainWindow._RE.ListEcoles();
foreach(string nomEcole in listEcoles)
{
    listEcole.Links.Add(new Link() 
    {
        DisplayName = nomEcole, 
        Source = new Uri("/Controles/EcoleControl.xaml", UriKind.Relative) 
    }); 
}
```

My problem is that i want to know the DisplayName of the selected link to put it in a property and use it in another UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var selectedLink = listEcole.Links.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Source == listEcole.SelectedSource);
if (selectedLink != null)
{
    string selectedDisplayName = selectedLink.DisplayName;
}
```

It should give you a reference to the currently selected `Link` in the `ModernTab`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This was exactly what I was looking for. It works and solves my problem !